# how to trim and append a string in for loop in c#

Tags: c#, foreach

how to trim and append a string in for loop in c# i have a string like `"\Examp"l'e"` and which i want is to get example from it using for each loop:

```
string value = @"\Examp"l'e";

foreach(string trim in value)
{
    if(trim == @"\")
    {
        \\how to trim the value like Examp"l'e
    }
    if(trim == @""")
    {
        \\again trim
    }
    if(trim == @"'")
    {
        \\again trim
    }
}
```

My final output should be: `Example`

Comment: Consider using replace to replace all unwanted characters with `string.Empty`

Answer (score 2):

Consider of using `string.Replace` for your task, it would have been easier:

```
string value = @"\Examp""l'e";
string final = value
   .Replace("\"", string.Empty)
   .Replace("\\", string.Empty)
   .Replace("'", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

brute force solution

do
 `trim.replace(oldvalue,"");`

better way

`Regex.Replace(trim, @"\"'", "");`

i have not tried this code,what i intend is you can use regex to trim.

Answer (score 1):

```
string value = @"\Examp"l'e";
value = value.Replace(@"\","").Replace("\"","").Replace("\'","");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"[\"']");
string value = @"\Examp"l'e";
string output = reg.Replace(value,String.Empty);
```

This will replace every character between the brackets in the regex by an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop and `String.Replace`(because you actually don't want to remove those characters from the start and the beginning but also from the middle):

```
string value = "\\Examp\"l'e";

string[] replaceAll = {"\\","\"", "'"};
foreach(string str in replaceAll)
    value = value.Replace(str, ""); 

Console.Write(value); // Example
```